# Error on building ng build --prod on angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have a problem while building for prod an angular cli project using angular 6.

At build it gives me ***ERROR in Cannot read property 'map' of undefined***

I tried to run ngc -p tsconfig.json and i got into a stacktrace saying 
***Cannot read property 'map' of undefined at AotCompiler.loadFilesAsync***

in this method (file: @angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js)

```
AotCompiler.prototype.loadFilesAsync = function (fileNames, tsFiles) {
        var _this = this;
        var files = fileNames.map(function (fileName) { return _this._analyzeFile(fileName); });
        var loadingPromises = [];
        files.forEach(function (file) { return file.ngModules.forEach(function (ngModule) {
            return loadingPromises.push(_this._metadataResolver.loadNgModuleDirectiveAndPipeMetadata(ngModule.type.reference, false));
        }); });
        var analyzedInjectables = tsFiles.map(function (tsFile) { return _this._analyzeFileForInjectables(tsFile); });
        return Promise.all(loadingPromises).then(function (_) { return ({
            analyzedModules: mergeAndValidateNgFiles(files),
            analyzedInjectables: analyzedInjectables,
        }); });
    };
```

I attached package.json and angular-cli.json files.

I run out of ideas and i do not know where to go next...
Thank you in advance.

package.json

```
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.9",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.9",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "6.0.0-beta.18",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.9",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.9",
    "@angular/material": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.9",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.9",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "latest",
    "angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
    "ng2-toastr": "^4.1.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.12.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "^2.9.2"
  }
}
```

angular.json

```
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "projectName": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/img"
            ],
            "styles": [
              {
                "input":"src/css/someStyle.scss"
              },
              "src/css/styles.css",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "projectName:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "projectName:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "projectName:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "scripts": [],
            "styles": [
              "src/css/styles.css"
            ],
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/img"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "projectName-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e",
      "sourceRoot": "e2e",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "./protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "projectName:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "provider:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "projectName",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": "app",
      "styleext": "css"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "app"
    }
  }
}
```

LATER EDIT:
i run the build with --aot=false --build-optimizer=false which is weird...

Comment: Sorry, but I think you need create clear new app, and then replace your code on the new platform

Comment: Hey, any reason why i need to do that? i managed to build for prod by using these parameters: ng build with --aot=false --build-optimizer=false which is weird...

Comment: @mariobyn can you try ```ng build --verbose``` for me to see if there any full error log ?

Comment: gives no error in verbose :(